# Is there a long version of IntPtr in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, 64-bit, 32-bit

I need an equivalent to `ULONG_PTR` from C++ in C#.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes me nervous. Can't I deal with 64-bit pointer in a 32-bit app ?

---

In case of suspicion for a XY Problem: I need an `OVERLAPPED` struct in C#. And it contains `ULONG_PTR`. Looks like this:

```
typedef struct _OVERLAPPED
{
    ULONG_PTR Internal;
    ULONG_PTR InternalHigh;
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            DWORD Offset;
            DWORD OffsetHigh;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
        PVOID Pointer;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
    HANDLE hEvent;
} OVERLAPPED, *LPOVERLAPPED;
```

Comment: Why would you need a 64bit pointer in a 32bit app..?

Comment: There's no such thing as a 64 bit pointer in a 32 bit app.

Comment: There's already an overlapped structure : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.overlapped(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [ULONG_PTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230394.aspx) maps to [__int3264](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241169.aspx), which is the same thing as `IntPtr`. There is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All pointers in a 32bit system are 32 bit and all pointers in a 64bit system are 64 bit natively. 64bit can emulate 32bit pointers for legacy applications that expect 32bit.

In a 32 bit system, you cannot have a 64bit pointer. If you could, of what use would 64bit systems be :)

You can use `System.IntPtr` for any pointer you encounter.